# Home layout missing in _layouts folder, but works

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I started to make my blog with jekyll and github pages.

I was doing fine with the basic theme,
But I wanted to apply the side bar property,
so I downloaded the theme which has the sidebar, from https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/

So I downloaded the proejct and overrided.
I don't know much about how this works,
but the strangest thing is that
in index.md file

if I put

```
---
layout:home
sidebar:mydoc_sidebar
----
```

it happens to show the basic theme layout
and the posts as it should be, but if I change the layout to
something else which is inside the _layout folder such as post, default,
the posts disappear and I have no idea why Jekyll does this.

Even when I erase the layout, it returns empty screen
so I'm sure it's doing something with the
home layout but I couldn't find anywhere how the home layout is rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ***_config.yml***, we can see that you are using (`theme: minima`) the *minima* gem based theme ([documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/)). That means that by default, all your *_includes*, *_layouts* and *assets* are hidden somewhere on you computer. You can use the `bundle show minima` command to find out where they are stored.

As *home* layout exists in *minima* theme, is it used.

If you want to use your own home layout you can copy it from *minima* to your *_layouts* folder and modify it to suits your needs.

```
cd your/root
cp `echo "$(bundle show minima)/_layouts/home.html" _layouts/home.html`
```

If you want to be sure not to use hidden resources, you can delete the `theme: minima` directive from your *_config.yml* file.

Comment: Thanks David! Had no Idea theme:minima was guilty for this!

Answer (score 0):

this issue can be caused by several factors but it is possible there's no issue at all :)

1) Stop Jekyll serve/watch.
2) Delete the `_site` directory.
3) Rebuild and serve the site

`jekyll serve`.

Keep an eye on the terminal to see if Jekyll warns you about the missing layout file.

It is possible, albeit unlikely that the theme or a plugin id building layouts on the fly. To override this (whether it is the case or not), create a `home` layout as usual and include in a page/post's front-matter. Just keep the layout basic with something like a red background so that you can easily test if it is loaded or not.

I think deleting the `_site` folder will fix this but if not, try the other option and let me know.